# C function to print maximum and minimum numbers

Tags: c

'm currently writing a C program that prompts a user to enter five numbers and to display the maximum number. So here's what i came up with

```
int max_num(float num_arr[])
// this is a number array        
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++)
    {
        max = num_arr[0];
        if (max > num_arr[k])
        { 
            max = num_arr[k];
            printf("The maximum number is is %d\n", max);
        }    
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is exavtly are you asking. Does your code work? Are you  not getting the expected result?

Comment: Normally, you have to pass the size of the array as a parameter. Also note that in [tag:c] there is no difference between `int max_num(float num_arr[])` and `int max_num(float *num_arr)`. Also it'shardtosee`max>num_arr[k]`aswhatitis. And no, your code "*is wrong*". You should return from the function or else it's undefined behavior, return `max` and don't print anything in it.

Comment: Use `max>=num_arr[k]`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yes you are right, my bad.

Comment: Be consistent: is the type `float` or is it `int`? Aside: always use `double` unless the appiclation cannot use `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function will not work for numbers entered less than 0, also int type is wrong for the fuunction since it's not returning anything. Here is a better version of the same:

```
void max_num(float num_arr[], int size)
{
    if(size>0) float max = num_arr[0];
    for (int k = 0; k <= size; k++) {
        if (max < num_arr[k]) {
            max = num_arr[k];
        }    
    }
    printf("The maximum number is %f\n", max);
}
```

And if you need to return max:

```
float max_num(float num_arr[], int size)        
{
    if(size>0) float max = num_arr[0];
    for (int k = 0; k <= size; k++) {
        if (max < num_arr[k]) {
            max = num_arr[k];
        }    
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: `for (int k = 0; k <= size; k++)` should be `for (int k = 1; k < size; k++)`

Comment: `printf("The maximum number is %d\n", max);` should be `printf("The maximum number is %f\n", max);`

Comment: Careful with corner cases: `float max = num_arr[0];` is a problem when `size <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting

```
max = num_arr[0];
```

in every loop iteration, so you are losing the max value every time and set it
to the first value in the array.

The correct version is:

```
for(int k = 0;k<5;k++)
{
    if(num_arr[k] > max)
        max = num_arr[k];
}

printf("The maximum number is is %d\n", max);
```

Having a `<=` in the condition is not incorrect, but it's not very readable either,
it's hard to miss the `=` sign. It's always better to just use `<`, in this case
`k<5`.

Also it's better practice to pass the size of the array to the functions, so you
don't have to hard code the maximal number of items to loop through (like you
did in your code). Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float max_num(float *array, size_t len)
{
    if(array == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid argument, array == NULL\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if(len == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid array size, cannot be 0\n");
        return 0;
    }

    float max = array[0];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] > max)
            max = array[i];
    }

    return max;
}

int main(void)
{
    float nums[] = { 1.1, -2.2, 8, 6, 99 , -12 };

    float max = max_num(nums, sizeof nums / sizeof *nums);

    printf("The maximal number in the array is: %f\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, I missed that. I fixed the answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If code is testing `if(array == NULL)`, might as well not assume `len > 0` for `len == 0` kills `float max = array[0];`.

Comment: @chux you're right, I should have checked for `len == 0` as well if I'm checking for everything. I've updated my answer, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `if(max > num_arr[k])` it should be `if(num_arr[k] > max)`